# Bitnami Redmineで参照先のDBを変更したい

Tags: mysql, redmine, bitnami

LAMP環境が構築されている「さくらのVPS」にBitnami Redmineのインストールをしましたが、
Bitnami付属のMySQLと、元々入っていたMySQLの同時起動は不可能な事を確認しました。

ApacheはRedmine側のポートを8081に変更することで同時起動ができたのですが、MySQLはポート変更では無くRedmineから参照しているDBを「RedmineのMySQL -> 元々入っていたMySQL」に変更したいと思っています。

検索エンジン等で探してみたりドキュメントを漁ったりしたのですが中々良い方法が見つからず困っています。
恐れながらご教授頂きたく存じます。

環境は以下の構成です。
CentOS 6.6
Bitnami Redmine 3.3
Apache 2.2.15
MySQL 14.14
PHP 5.5

Comment: ご質問の内容としては参照しているDBの切り替えができないのか、それとも切り替えたけどもデータベースのマイグレーションができないのどちらですかね？

Comment: keitaro_so様、ご質問ありがとうございます。参照しているDBの切り替えができない件になります。

Comment: ちなみに接続できないということはmysqlエラーが出ているのかと思いますが、どのようなmysqlエラーがでているか記述できますか？

Comment: @keitaro_so
database.ymlを変更後
/opt/redmine/ctlscript.sh start
で下記エラーが表示されます。
`
# /opt/redmine/ctlscript.sh start
191002 17:12:48 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/redmine/mysql/data/mysqld.log'.
191002 17:12:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld.bin daemon with databases from /opt/redmine/mysql/data
191002 17:12:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/redmine/mysql/data/mysqld.pid ended
/opt/redmine/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  could not be started
Syntax OK
/opt/redmine/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
`

Comment: ctlscript.shは接続をするためのスクリプトではなくてRedmineを利用するにあたって必要なサービスを起動するためのスクリプトなので、別のMySQLが起動中であれば、実行する必要はないと思います。それをしないとredmineは起動しないですか？

Comment: ctlscript.shに関しては知識不足でした。ありがとうございます。/opt/redmine/ctlscript.sh stop mysqlにてmysqlをストップすると「Internal error」エラーにてブラウザからのアクセスができなくなってしまう現状です。

Comment: Internal error ということはどこかでエラーが発生していますね。Redmineのログやapacheのエラーログを確認してください。そのうえでわからないことがあればまた質問していただければと思います。

Comment: BitnamiにはApacheも含まれているはずなので、元々のLAMP環境のApacheとどちらを使うのか(それとも本当に両方必要？)や、LAMPのMySQLを使うならBitnamiの環境は忘れて一からセットアップした方が近道のような気がします (データは必要に応じて手動で移行すればよいでしょう)。

Comment: お二方とも、アドバイス頂き誠にありがとうございます。参考に一旦環境を見つめ直したいと思います。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

RedmineでDBの接続先はインストールディレクトリ以下にある `config/database.yml` という設定ファイルで管理されているはずなので、この記述を適切な情報に書き換えてみてください。

**/opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/database.yml**

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: bitnami_redmine
  host: localhost
  username: bitnami
  password: xxxxxxxx
  xxxxxx
```

Comment: cubick様  
コメントありがとうございます。
/opt/[インストールフォルダ]/apps/redmine/htdocs/config/database.yml
を
`
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: bitnami_redmine
  host: localhost
  username: [移行先DBのusername]
  password:  [移行先DBのpassword]
  encoding: utf8
  socket: /opt/redmine/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
  `
  adapterをmysqlに変更したり移行先のsocketを調べて変更してみたりしたのですがどうも接続ができない状態です。
  ポートの指定等をする必要があるのでしょうか。。。

Comment: 参照先の `database:` も、テーブルデータをそのまま移行したのでなければ適切な名前に書き換える必要があるかと思います。 / Bitnami 付属のMySQLを停止、標準のMySQLに対してコマンドラインから接続できるか試す…など、順を追って確認していくとよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。database名に関してはそのままインポートしたので変更する必要はないと思いますが、アドバイス頂いた通り順を追って確認してみます。